# ext sheaf, homological dimension and locally free sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf in $X$. We define the homological dimension of $\mathcal{F}$, denoted $hd(\mathcal{F})$, to be the least lenght of a locally free resolution of $\mathcal{F}$. Then,

a) $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free $\Leftrightarrow hd(\mathcal{F}) = 0$

b) $hd(\mathcal{F}) \leq n$ $\Leftrightarrow ext^{p}(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})  = 0 $ for all  $p > n$ and all $\mathcal{G} \in \mathfrak{Mod}(X)$.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried the following : for all   coherent sheaf on $X$ there is an exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow F_{r-i} \longrightarrow F_{r} \cdots \longrightarrow F_{0}  \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}  \longrightarrow 0$$ where $F_{i}$ are locally free sheaves. I can do the item (a), My problem now is the item (b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that you can compute the $ext$ sheaves using a resolution of the first argument by locally free sheaves. Using this, the direct implication in (b) is obvious.

The only non trivial part is then the converse. So let's assume that $hd(\mathcal{F})>n$ and consider a resolution 
$$F_{n+1}\to F_n\to F_{n-1}\to...\to F_0\to\mathcal{F}\to 0$$
with the $F_i$ being locally free.

One of the most useful trick in homological algebra is to split this sequence into short exact ones :
$$0\to Z_n\to F_n\to Z_{n-1}\to 0$$
$$0\to Z_{n-1}\to F_{n-1}\to Z_{n-2}\to 0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$0\to Z_0\to F_0\to \mathcal{F}\to 0$$
With $Z_i=\ker(F_i\to F_{i-1})=\operatorname{im}(F_{i+1}\to F_i)$. (And $Z_{-1}=\mathcal{F}$ so that the proof also work if $n=0$).

From the long exact sequence associated to each of these short exact sequences, we get 
$ext^{n+1}(\mathcal{F,G})=ext^n(Z_0,\mathcal{G})=ext^{n-1}(Z_1,\mathcal{G})=...=ext^1(Z_{n-1},\mathcal{G})$.
So to conclude the proof, it is enough to find $\mathcal{G}$ such that $ext^1(Z_{n-1},\mathcal{G})\neq 0$.

By assumption $Z_{n-1}=\ker(F_{n-1}\to F_{n-2})$ is not locally free (otherwise we would be able to construct a locally free resolution of length $n$). So in the short exact sequence
$$0\to Z_n\to F_n\to Z_{n-1}\to 0$$
we have $Z_{n-1}$ not locally free and $F_n$ locally free (and thus $Z_n\neq 0$).

Take $\mathcal{G}=Z_n$, then we have a short exact sequence 
$$0\to\mathcal{H}om(Z_{n-1},Z_n)\to\mathcal{H}om(F_n,Z_n)\to\mathcal{H}om(Z_n,Z_n)$$
I claim that the last map in this sequence is not onto. If it were, then $\operatorname{id}_{Z_n}\in\operatorname{Hom}(Z_n,Z_n)=\mathcal{H}om(Z_n,Z_n)(X)$ would have local preimage in $\mathcal{H}om(F_n,Z_n)$. This mean that there would be local retractions of $Z_n\to F_n$, so the sequence $0t\to Z_n\to F_n\to Z_{n-1}\to 0$ would be locally split. But this would mean $Z_{n-1}$ is locally free (it would be locally a direct factor of a locally free module). Since this is not the case, $\mathcal{H}om(F_n,Z_n)\to\mathcal{H}om(Z_n,Z_n)$ is not onto.

This implies that $ext^1(Z_{n-1},Z_n)\neq 0$ and that concludes the proof.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: @AllanRamos If you are satisfy with this answer, you should accept it so that your question won't be mark as unanswered.

Comment: How do I do this? I'm new to the forum. Thank you.

Comment: taking the opportunity, I just did not understand the part:  If it were, there would be local retractions of $Z_{n} \rightarrow F_{n}$. Thank you.

Comment: Left to the beginning of the answer there should be a zero (the current note), an arrow up (to upvote an answer) an arrow down (to say that an answer was not good) and below the acceptation mark. As for the part you didn't understand, I will edit my answer, tell me if it is clearer that way.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much, Roland.

Comment: @Roland, is it true that for a general sheaf of noncommutative rings $\mathcal{A}_X$ on a topological space $X$ and left $\mathcal{A}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{G}$, you can compute $\mathcal{Ext}_{\mathcal{A}_X}^{\bullet}(F, G)$ using a resolution of the first argument $\mathcal{F}$ by locally free $\mathcal{A}_X$-modules? I think it is not clear if you mean $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules or general sheaves of rings.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius I guess so : $\mathcal{E}xt^n_{\mathcal{A}_X}(F,G)$ is the sheafification of $U\mapsto \operatorname{Ext}^n_{\mathcal{A}_U}(F|_U,G|_U)$. This implies that if $F$ is locally free, then $\mathcal{E}xt^n_{\mathcal{A}_X}(F,G)=0$ for any sheaf $G$. Hence, the usual argument shows that you can use locally free sheaves to resolve the first argument.

Comment: @ Rolland, Yes, thank you. Your argument is very good. May I ask you something else which is not answered in the literature? If $X$ is a topological space (not necessarily manifold or variety) and $\mathcal{R}$ is a sheaf of (not necessarily commutative) rings and $M, N$ are (left) $\mathcal{R}$-modules, is it true that $R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, N)\cong R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, \mathcal{R})\otimes^LN$. This isomorphism is true in the category of $R$-modules but does the statement remain true in the category of modules of sheaves of rings? I cannot find any reference for sheaves.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius I doubt this is true (even in the category of $R$-modules) without any assumptions on $M$ and $N$. I believe that $M=N=\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}$ is a counter-example (with $R=\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: About my comment on $\mathcal{E}xt^n$. There is an argument I skipped : why $F$ locally free implies that $\mathcal{E}xt^n(F,G)=0$. This is because for a trivializing open set $U$, $\operatorname{Ext}^n(F|_U,G|_U)\simeq\bigoplus H^n(U,G|_U)$ and we knows that that this presheaf sheafifies to 0.

Comment: @Roland, In Michel van den Bergh's paper "A relation between Hochschild homology and cohomology for Gorenstein rings" (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-05/S0002-9939-98-04210-5/S0002-9939-98-04210-5.pdf ) in the proof of Theorem 1, the author uses this relation without making any obvious to me assumptions. I have seen this relation also for $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules in Lemma 2.6.13 in Ryoshi Hotta's book on D-modules (https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cautis/dmodules/hottaetal.pdf). It should hold true in great generality possibly up to some mild assumptions but I cannot  prove it.

Comment: @Roland, Thank you for the additional clarification. I appreciate that.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius I checked and a sufficient condition for the isomorphism to hold in the (abelian, not derived) category of $R$-modules is that $M$ is finitely presented. For a sheaf and derived version, you will need that $M$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex of locally free sheaves. In your second link, this was indeed an assumption.

Comment: Wait! The isomorphism $RHom_{R}(M, N)\cong RHom_{R}(M, R)\otimes^L N$ should hold true in the derived category of $R$-modules, not the abelian, right? What do you mean by the not derived category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131415/discussion-between-roland-and-flavius-aetius).

Comment: @Roland, I am sorry for my absence. I would like to continue the discussion. What I cannot completely figure out yet is how you prove that $R\mathcal{Hom}_R(M, N)\cong R\mathcal{Hom}_R(M, R)\otimes_R^LN$ when M has a locally free resolution of finite rank and length $P^{\bullet}\to M$.

Comment: @Roland, Unfortunately, I think that it is not enough for $M$ to be quasi-isomorphic to a complex of locally free sheaves of finite length. Then, M would be simply an element in the derived category $D_{qc}^b$ of bounded complexes with quasi-coherent cohomology sheaves, not necessarily an element in the derived category $D_c^b$ of bounded complexes with coherent cohomology sheaves as it is asked in Hotta's book in Lemma $2.6.13$. That might be a problem.

Comment: @FlaviusAetius You should post another question with the exact assumptions. I will probably answer it, or maybe someone else will, but I need to read again all what we have written. We talk about different sets of assumptions, different situations, so I am kind of lost in what you want to prove exactly. Moreover, the discussion came really far from the OP, so this won't be a bad thing.

Comment: @Roland, Ok. I will post another question tomorrow here. The question basically is: under which conditions does the identity $R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, N)=R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, \mathcal{R})\otimes_{\mathcal{R}}^LN$ hold true in the derived category where $\mathcal{R}$ is a sheaf of rings and $M$ and $N$ are $\mathcal{R}$-modules. You said that this was the case when $M$ admits a finite locally free resolution of $\mathcal{R}$-modules. I disagree now. I think that $M$ needs to be $\mathcal{R}$-coherent, too.

Comment: @Roland, I posted the question as promised yesterday. Here is a direct link to the the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372286/a-condition-for-the-validity-of-an-identity-in-the-derived-category-of-bounded-c

Comment: @Roland, I posted a question on Mathoverflow on the same topic. If you are interested, any comments and answers by you would be highly appreciated  there. Here is the link to the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415391/pseudo-coherent-complexes-over-sheaves-of-non-commutative-rings

Comment: @FlaviusAetius Yes I saw it, sorry I don't have much time right now. I will think about it, but give me a few days. Right now, I don't see the objection, but I haven't given much thoughts. I promise I will take a more serious look.

Comment: @Roland, absolutely no problem! Of course, you should focus on your work primarily! Intuitively, I am actually quite certain that you are right but since the non-commutative setting is more tricky than the standard commutative setting in which these statements are proved in the literature, I need to be very careful.