# A condition for the validity of an identity in the derived category of bounded complexes of modules.

Tags: homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a sheaf of (not necessarily commutative) rings on a topological space $X$ and let $M$ and $N$ be $\mathcal{R}-$modules such that $M$ is quasi-isomorphic to a finite complex of locally free $\mathcal{R}$-modules of finite rank. Can we infer from these assumptions that there is an isomorphism
$$R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, \mathcal{R})\otimes_{\mathcal{R}}^LN\cong R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(M, N)$$
in the derived category $D^b(\mathcal{R})$ of bounded $\mathcal{R}$-modules? In particular, do we need to assume in addition that $M$ is a coherent $\mathcal{R}$-module or the existence of a finite resolution of locally free $\mathcal{R}$-modules of finite rank suffices?

Comment: Probably the answer to that question is contained in Lemma 2.6.13 in Hotta's book https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cautis/dmodules/hottaetal.pdf. The module $M$ is supposed to be a pseudo-coherent bounded complex in the derived category of $\mathcal{R}$-modules which, as user @Roland suggested on a different post some time ago, is probably precisely equivalent to the fact that $M$ is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded above complex of locally free $\mathcal{R}$-modules of finite rank. But I am still curious about the expert's comments and answers to that question.

Comment: With regard to the above comment of mine, I am not sure if we should not in addition assume that the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{R}$ is coherent. I wonder because $\mathcal{D}_X$ is coherent. A comment on that would be very helpful. Thanks.